# Customising rails Routes for user - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could one advise me how to get a url like this in rails

http://www.example.com/users/5/ian

i tried the below but unsure:

```
route file:
devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :socials
  end
  get '/users/:id/:firstname', controller: 'users', action: 'show'
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id], params[:firstname])
  end
```

Comment: If you want to check the results of your configuration of routes.rb simply use `rake routes` from the terminal - this will display all the generated routes.

Comment: Why would you want to use both an id and a username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to achieve 'friendly urls' then I suggest using this:

You don't have to create a special route:

```
get '/users/:id', controller: 'users', action: 'show'
```

Instead you have your model overwrite the to_param method:

```
class User
  ...
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{firstname.try(:parameterize)}"
  end
  ...
end
```

The url helper calls to_param to build the urls. If you overwrite it this way, you will receive a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1-artloe
```

The rails find method calls .to_i on the params[:id] which, thankfully, interprets strings as number until it arrives at a character that can't become a number.

Examples:

```
'123abcde'.to_i # 123
'123-asdf'.to_i # 123
'asdf-123'.to_i # 0
```

So except for overwriting to_param, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: You should still ensure that `firstname` is value that is URL safe. In many locales a first name can be a compound name with a space in it for example. Which is why the OP really should look at FriendlyId and Stringex which solve the hard questions related to slugging which is actually surprisingly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_id_and_firstname(params[:id], params[:firstname])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying accomplish is "friendly urls" you would do it by:

```
# GET /users/1
# GET /users/joe
def show
  @user = User.find_by!('id = :x OR firstname = :x', x: params[:id]) 
end
```

However you must ensure that property you are using in URLs is URL safe and unique. Usually a separate username or slug field is used. 
Nothing special is needed in terms of routes.

These gems provide "friendly urls":

- [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex)
- [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)